# Wix: change installation folder tree

Tags: wix, installation, directory

I've a set of folder to be installed in different layouts for different users. For examle:

```
User1:
    AppFolder
        Dir1
        Dir2
           Dir3

  User2:
     AppFolder
         Bin
           Dir1
           Dir2
         Lib
           Dir3
```

How it's possible?

Comment: What is your reason for doing this?  This is not a good idea.

Comment: I've two different environments.
For each of the environments, the compiled binaries should be arranged differentely.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of detail in the question, so I'll have to guess a bit. You can treat Directories a lot like Properties. So, you could do something like:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
  <Directory Id="AppFolder" Name="PFiles">
    <Directory Id="BinFolder" Name="Bin">
       <Directory Id="Dir1" Name="Dir1" />
       <Directory Id="Dir2" Name="Dir2" />
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="LibFolder" Name="Lib">
       <Directory Id="Dir3" Name="Dir3" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<SetProperty Id="BinFolder" Value="[AppFolder]" After="CostFinalize">HOW_EVER_USER2_DETECTED</SetProperty>
<SetProperty Id="LibFolder" Value="[Dir2]" After="CostFinalize">HOW_EVER_USER2_DETECTED</SetProperty>
```

That may not be exactly correct but it'll get you close. You might also look at using a CustomAction element that uses the Directory and Value attributes to redirect if the Property mechanism doesn't work perfectly.

Also, like others have mentioned. This is weird. I'd suggest removing the requirement from the product. ;)